# PUT/POST Key/Value collection to OpenRasta

Tags: openrasta

How should an OpenRasta handler be implemented such that it can accept a URL-template based ID together with a dictionary, Hashtable or NameValueCollection (I don't care which one)?

My URL-template is "/fielddata/{correlationId}".

My PUT message is:

```
PUT http://myhost/fielddata/39950 HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 14

X=123&Y=Abc
```

I have tried a handler like this:

```
public class FieldDataHandler
{
  public void Put(string correlationId, NameValueCollection data)
  {
  }
}
```

But get an exception like this:

```
openrasta Verbose: 0 : Incoming host request for http://myhost/fielddata/39950
openrasta Verbose: 0 : Adding communication context data
openrasta Verbose: 0 : Found 1 operation(s) with a matching name.
openrasta Verbose: 0 : Found 0 operation(s) with matching [HttpOperation] attribute.
openrasta Information: 0 : Operation FieldDataHandler::Put(String correlationId, NameValueCollection data) selected with 2 required members and 0 optional members, with codec ApplicationXWwwFormUrlencodedKeyedValuesCodec with score 1,333333.
openrasta Error: 0 : An error has occurred and the processing of the request has stopped.

Exception:
System.InvalidOperationException: The operation is not ready for invocation.
   at OpenRasta.OperationModel.MethodBased.MethodBasedOperation.Invoke() in c:\Projects\OpenRasta\openrasta-stable\src\core\OpenRasta\OperationModel\MethodBased\MethodBasedOperation.cs:line 56
   at OpenRasta.OperationModel.Interceptors.OperationWithInterceptors.<Invoke>b__0() in c:\Projects\OpenRasta\openrasta-stable\src\core\OpenRasta\OperationModel\Interceptors\OperationWithInterceptors.cs:line 47
   at OpenRasta.OperationModel.Interceptors.OperationWithInterceptors.Invoke() in c:\Projects\OpenRasta\openrasta-stable\src\core\OpenRasta\OperationModel\Interceptors\OperationWithInterceptors.cs:line 52
   at OpenRasta.OperationModel.OperationExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 operations) in c:\Projects\OpenRasta\openrasta-stable\src\core\OpenRasta\OperationModel\OperationExecutor.cs:line 14
   at OpenRasta.Pipeline.Contributors.OperationInvokerContributor.ExecuteOperations(ICommunicationContext context) in c:\Projects\OpenRasta\openrasta-stable\src\core\OpenRasta\Pipeline\Contributors\OperationInvokerContributor.cs:line 29
   at OpenRasta.Pipeline.PipelineRunner.ExecuteContributor(ICommunicationContext context, ContributorCall call) in c:\Projects\OpenRasta\openrasta-stable\src\core\OpenRasta\Pipeline\PipelineRunner.cs:line 187
openrasta Information: 0 : Executing OperationResult OperationResult: type=InternalServerError, statusCode=500.
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up fixing this by creating a new Codec for a domain specific resource type (instead of the generic NameValueCollection type) and then do the form-urlencoded (de)serialization by other means.

The codec itself looks like this:

```
[MediaType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
public class RestFieldDataCodec : IMediaTypeWriter, IMediaTypeReader
{
  public void WriteTo(object entity, IHttpEntity response, string[] codecParameters)
  {
    RestFieldData data = (RestFieldData)entity;

    using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(response.Stream))
    {
      FormUrlEncodingSerializer serializer = new FormUrlEncodingSerializer(typeof(NameValueCollection));
      serializer.Serialize(writer, data.Data);
    }
  }


  public object ReadFrom(IHttpEntity request, IType destinationType, string destinationName)
  {
    using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(request.Stream))
    {
      FormUrlEncodingSerializer serializer = new FormUrlEncodingSerializer(typeof(NameValueCollection));
      NameValueCollection keyValueData = (NameValueCollection)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
      return new RestFieldData
      {
        Data = keyValueData
      };
    }
  }


  public object Configuration { get; set; }
}
```

And the resource type is rather simple:

```
public class RestFieldData
{
  public NameValueCollection Data { get; set; }
}
```

The FormUrlEncodingSerializer class is from https://github.com/JornWildt/Ramone

The handler method ended up like this:

```
public void Put(string correlationId, RestFieldData payload)
{
  ...
}
```